# Converting a function into an arrow

Tags: javascript

I have the following basic js function:

```
function copy_array(arr) {
    // copy array and return existing array
    const cp = [];
    for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
        cp[i] = arr[i];
    return cp;
}
```

Is it possible to convert this into an arrow function, for example:

```
const copy_array2 = (arr) => {
   // ?
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can put the same code within your regular function into your arrow function

Comment: Why do you think it would be any different?

Comment: Arrow functions are missing a few features from regular functions (such as `arguments`), but you don't use any of them.

Comment: @NickParsons I see. So is there any advantage of having the above as an Arrow function, or in the above case it's irrelevant.

Comment: @David542 for the above example I can't think of any advantages of using an arrow function, but if you had different code within your function then it might be more appropriate to use an arrow function (you can see: [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379) for more details about the differences).

Comment: voting to close as dup. Not helpful or anything new for future users.

Comment: `const copyArray2 = arr => arr.map(x=>x);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```js
const copy_array2 = (arr) => {
    const cp = [];
    for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
        cp[i] = arr[i];
    return cp;

}

const arr = [1, 2, 3]
const copy = copy_array2(arr)

arr[0] = 5

console.log(copy)
```